# Force Orientation on certain pages

Tags: android, ios, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm developing a PhoneGap + JSmobile + html5 app for iOS and Android. I'd like to force the landscape orientation for same pages. I'm trying to find a solution but I can't do it.
Is it possible at all?

I found a post where someone says to use a trick in CSS to rotate the #div:

```
#ID {
-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

this trick rotates the page but it is rendered with with a border on the left and right side.

Comment: give it also width: 100 !important;

Comment: ..same problem...i think it was due to:         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
but how can'i set width=device-heght and heght=device-width only for same page?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found a solution:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#ID',function() {        
                setTimeout(function() {
                                  $('head').append( '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-height, height=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;">' );
                                  }, 200);
                       });
```

the timeout is to prevent strange change in the prev page ;)

Comment: This does not rotate the device on an iphone.